# Нужно изменить данные и обновить эту же страницу при нажатии кнопки

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, mvc

Не могу понять как реализовать функцию, которая при нажатии кнопки будет принимать id и по нему изменять атрибут из моей таблицы. Код который я написал возвращает не существующую страницу, а мне надо чтобы он изменил данные и обновил ту же самую страницу. Что я делаю не так или тут не надо использовать ActionLin?

```
 <tr>
               <td>@Html.ActionLink("Изменить на готово", "EditToReady", new { id = o.ServiceId })</td>
               <td>@o.ServiceId</td>
 </tr>
```

Код в контролере

```
 [HttpPost]
        public RedirectResult EditToReady(int id)
        {

            Service sevice = EF.Services
                .FirstOrDefault(g => g.ServiceId == id);


            sevice.StatusOfOrder = "Готово";
            EF.SaveChanges();


            return Redirect("/Admin/Services");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Допер, что надо было использовать HttpGet

```
[HttpGet]
        public RedirectResult EditToReady(int id)
        {

            Service sevice = EF.Services
                .FirstOrDefault(g => g.ServiceId == id);


            sevice.StatusOfOrder = "Готово";
            EF.SaveChanges();
            return Redirect("/Admin/Services");
        }
```

Comment: На `GET` делать обновление базы не хорошо.

Comment: Можно узнать почему и как правильнее и лучше?

Comment: Запостил отдельным ответом.

Answer (score 0):

`GET` не рекомендуется использовать для обновления базы, т.к. он предназначается для получения (get) информации от сервера ([GET Verb](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/GET)), такой запрос должен быть идемпотентен (свойство, при котором запрос может быть сделан несколько раз с одинаковыми параметрами и приведет к одну и тому же результату). Также такие запросы могут кешироваться браузерами/проксями, что приведет к выполнению запроса только один раз. Или если пользователь обновил страницу и запрос будет выполнен несколько раз. В вашем конкретном случае все эти пункты может не затрагивать вам, но это общепринятое соглашение, что `GET` запрос является "безопасным".

В вашем случае можно ссылку обернуть в форму, например:

```
<td>
  <form asp-action="EditToReady" asp-controller="имя_контроллера">
    <input type="submit" value="Изменить на готово" />
  </form>
</td>
```

Или при помощи `Html.BeginForm`.

Comment: Спасибо большое